# Labeling the peaks in a list plot

Tags: plotting, marker

I'm doing some research on Raman spectroscopy and I would like to present my data in a similar way to this example that I found in a book. The data that I adquired is similar. I have identified the peaks using some Lorentz-Cauchy fitting and now I would like to put markers on top of the peaks that I obtained. I have made a list plot of the data. It plots correctly. Now I would like to add some labels on top of the peaks in a way similar to that shown below.. I was wondering if any of you have suggestions of hoe I can do to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Please include a MWE in order to get help...

Comment: I'm impressed with the answers i have got ,thank you so much!
I didnt expect so much detail ,and to get answered so fast.
I'll try to implement the suggestions as soon as i can.
Thanks for the help

Comment: @Alejandro, if you find a particular answer to be satisfactory, click on the checkmark to the left of the answer, below the arrows. Next time, please include raw data if you are asking questions about plotting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it;

```
data = Table[{x, Exp[-80 (x - 1)^2] + 0.7 Exp[-25 (x - 2)^2]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.05}]; 
 (*just a test data with two peaks*)

peaks = data[[#]] & /@ FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]]][[All, 1]]; (*find peaks in your data*)
textshift = {0.1, 0}; (*where the text would be wrt the point*) 

ListLinePlot[data, Epilog -> {Point[peaks],
             Text[Rotate[#[[2]], Pi/2], # + textshift] & /@ peaks}]
```

[image]

Comment: With version 11.0 or later `ListPlot[{data, Callout[#, Rotate[#[[1]], Pi/2], Above] & /@ peaks}, Joined -> {True, False}]` for labels corresponding to x-axis.

Comment: @Sumit i have managed to recreate on my notebook ,the solution you gave me with my data.now i'm wondering if there is anyway to increase the size of the text that the epilog show.

Comment: @Alejandro, you can use `Text[Rotate[Style[#[[2]],12,Bold,Red], Pi/2]` for Bold and red text with font size 12 for example. You can use any style with `Style`.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using `Callout`.

First I will contrives some data that look somewhat like yours.

```
SeedRandom[1];
{data, peaks} =
  Module[{ymax = 100., nPeaks = 7, peakAt = 3, xvals, yvals, peaks, noise, data},
   xvals = Subdivide[200, 1700, nPeaks - 1] // N;
   yvals =
     Join[Reverse[Range[peakAt - 1]] ymax/6, {ymax}, Range[nPeaks - peakAt] ymax/9];
   peaks = Transpose[{xvals, yvals}];
   noise =
     Transpose[{Subdivide[200., 1700., 99], RandomReal[ymax {1./30, 1./20}, 100]}];
   data = Sort[Join[peaks, noise]];
   {data, peaks}];
```

The data looks like this:

```
ListLinePlot[data,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Automatic},
  PlotRange -> All,
  AxesOrigin -> {1800, 0},
  Ticks -> {Range[0, 2000, 200], Automatic}]
```

[image: data_plot]

Now I find the peaks in the data and wrap them with a simple callout that gives the x-axis values of the peak.

```
 plotData = If[MemberQ[peaks, #], Callout[#, #[[1]]], #] & /@ data;
```

`Callout` takes additional arguments and options that allow a lot fancy styling and placement modifications to the callouts, but in this case, I think the defaults work well, so I kept things simple.

Here is plot with the callouts:

```
ListLinePlot[plotData,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Automatic},
  PlotRange -> All,
  AxesOrigin -> {1800, 0},
  Ticks -> {Range[0, 2000, 200], Automatic}]
```

[image: callout_plot]

This approach requires you have a list of the peak points as well as a list of the data points. The way I read your question suggests to me that you do, which is why I think you might find this answer helpful.